# mvc dropdownlist - capturing change event without attaching the event handler

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I know I can attach change event to html.dropdownlist in mvc as shown below:

```
$('#ddList').change(function() {
            var value = $(this).val();


        });
```

However, is there a way I can do it more like

```
 <%=Html.DropDownList("ddList", Model.dropDown, new { @class = "Ddl", change = "ddListChange"  })%>
```

js function below:

```
function ddListChange() {
        alert("test");
    }
```

Also, is one more approach more preferred than the other?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you were close, as the [`onchange`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) attribute was what you were looking for.

`<%= Html.DropDownList("ddList", Model.dropDown, new { @class = "Ddl", onchange = "ddListChange"  }) %>`

jQuery skips the `on` part of the event names in its methods/parameters for events, e.g. `.click(...) / .bind('click',..)` equals the `onClick` attribute.

Binding event handlers using javascript itself is the preferred way. Just like you separate styling into separate CSS files, you separate scripting into your own scripting files. This allows the HTML file to be cleaner and easier to read, in addition to separating the concerns of prensentation and whatever your scripts is doing. It also makes it easier for you page to degrade gracefully (work even if scripts aren't enabled).

[Here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/09/16/jquery-examples-and-best-practices/) is one article discussing the issue