# How to access js variable in view, Html.DropDownList?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the javasctipt variable

```
 var orgCode = "";
        $("#orgs").change(function () {
            var org = document.getElementById("orgs");
            orgCode = org.options[org.selectedIndex].value;

        });
```

I want to pass `orgCode` to my DropDownList all time, when the variable changes:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Doctor, new SelectList(_unitOfWork.Doctors.GetByOrganization(orgCode).ToList(), "Code", "Name"), new { id = "docs" })
```

my `orgCode` always changes, but how can I access it in DropDownList and refresh it each time with variable changes?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you want to bind the new codes on change?? what is `$("#orgs")`?

Comment: Please take a look at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160735/mvc-dropdownlist-capturing-change-event-without-attaching-the-event-handler

Comment: Nithesh, $("#orgs") is another dropdownlist which i get the needed code from

Comment: the result of unitOfWork.Doctors.GetByOrganization(orgCode) is the List of items, so i cannot just change the value of $('#docs') DropDownList, because it should contain several values.

Comment: is there an `action method` which returns `Doctors list` based on `orgs code`?

Comment: no, if it was, how can I pass the orgCode into it?

Comment: have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
$("#orgs").change(function () {
      var orgCode = $("#orgs").val();
      $.ajax({
          url:"controler/action", // which returns Dotors list as json
          data:{org_Code:orgCode} ,//Passing orgCode to the above action method
          type:"json",
          success:function(data){
             $('#docs').find('option').remove();
             foreach(var d in data){
                 $('<option>').val(d["code"]).text(d["Name"]).appendTo('#docs');
             }
          }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set selected value for dropdown whenever variable changes: ie;

```
 var orgCode = "";
 $("#orgs").change(function () {
    var org = document.getElementById("orgs");
    orgCode = org.options[org.selectedIndex].value;
    $('#docs').val(orgCode);
 });
```